# Riak search queries via the java client

Tags: riak, java-client

I am trying to perform queries using the OR operator as following:

> ```
>   MapReduceResult result = riakClient.
>             mapReduce("some_bucket", "Name:c1 OR c2").
>             addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), true).
>             execute();
> ```

I only get the 1st object in the query (where name='c1').
If I change the order of the query (i.e. Name:c2 OR c1) again I get only the first object in query (where name='c2').

is the OR operator (and other query operators) supported in the java client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from Basho engeneer, Sean C.:

> You either need to group the terms or qualify both of them. Without a field identifier, the search query assumes that the default field is being searched. You can determine how the query will be interpreted by using the 'search-cmd explain' command.  Here's two alternate ways to express your query:
>
> **Name:c1 OR Name:c2**
>
> **Name:(c1 OR c2)**

both options worked for me!